# SCSS styling inside of ion-item (Ionic framework)

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, styling

I am struggling with getting styling correct.  I think it is related to hierarchy of styling of the various ionic tags, but I am unsure.

In my app, I am trying to center some `<ion-button>` tags inside of columns of an `<ion-grid>`.

The result I keep getting is left-aligned buttons like this:
[image]

I have tried a variety of styles and classes to center the buttons.  I have tried them at every level of the hierarchy (at the ion-item, grid, row, col, label, buttons, button levels), but I keep getting the same result.

Here is the structure of the item.  In this iteration, you can see that I was trying to use the `text-center` attribute at the level of the row:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row text-center>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-label>
          <ion-buttons>
            <ion-button> Problem? </ion-button>
          </ion-buttons>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <ion-label>
          <ion-buttons>
            <ion-button>More</ion-button>
          </ion-buttons>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

I've read the ionic documentation on the scss styling, but they don't discuss nested items like a grid inside of an ion-item.

I suspect that some element's styling is over-riding my attempt to center the buttons here and I need to understand the basic principle of styling hierarchy.  Is there a place to go to learn this?

I've included the entire .scss file for reference, but I suspect I'm missing a principle:

```
.ios,
.md {
  page-home {
    #container {
      text-align: left;

      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    #container strong {
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 26px;
    }

    #container p {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 22px;

      color: #8c8c8c;

      margin: 0;
    }

    #container a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    ion-item {
      padding-top: 0.5rem;
    }

    .center-button {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-item: center;
    }

    ion-col {
      text-align: left;
    }

    ion-label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    ion-title {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .item-name {
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the ionic version you using?

Comment: Current Version = 6.17.0

Comment: Try `expand=block` on the ion-button. So `<ion-button expand="block"> Problem? </ion-button>`. Also You can try removing the `<ion-button>` from the `<ion-buttons>` tag. In ion-button text is by default centered. Expand Block will expand the button to all the space available. So you can get rid of the Ion-label and ion-buttons tag. try to put it directly under ion-col tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding these two css properties to ion-label

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I thought that should work too, but no dice.  I think there must be some other styling that is overriding the page's scss page.

Comment: If that is the case, try putting !important on these.

Comment: That's a terrific idea too, but I'm still stuck.   I'll poke at it some more over the weekend and report a solution once I find it.  I suspect conflicting specifications.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be the right way to solve the problem, but this is what I eventually did:  I just put the styling information inline in the HTML.  Here's an example:

```
      <ion-row style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
        <ion-item style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
          <ion-col size="4" style="align-content: center">
            <ion-buttons style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
              <ion-button
                style="width: 100%; text-align: center"
                (click)="onClickProblem('button', item.name)"
              >
                Problem?
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col
            size="4"
            style="width: 100%; text-align: center"
            *ngIf="item.notes"
          >
            <ion-buttons style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
              <ion-button
                style="width: 100%; text-align: center"
                (click)="onClickMore('button', item.notes)"
                >More</ion-button
              >
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-col>
```

You can see the `"width: 100%; text-align: center"` throughout.  It is not the most maintainable solution, but it got me out of the purgatory of no progress.